# Conversion from hexadecimal string to double in C++

Tags: c++, hex, double

I have a string in byte that represent a double number. It is like this in hexadecimal format:

```
char buffer[17] = "4053E60C49BA5E35";
```

In double the correct value is: 21,898625.
I need a simple way to convert this string in double. The only way that work just now is this, but I'm not sure it this the best way:

```
double hexstr2double(const std::string& hexstr)
{
  union
  {
     long long i;
     double    d;
  } value;

  try{
    value.i = std::stoll(hexstr, nullptr, 16);
  }
  catch(...){value.i=0;}

  return value.d;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: This way invokes Undefined Behaviour. You cannot access any other union member than the one that you last wrote to.

Comment: If you want to convert an integer to a floating point type byte-wise, then you need `memcpy`, not type punning through a union since that is not allowed in C++.

Comment: can you show me an example? tnx

Comment: You can use [std::strtod](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof). You just need to prepend "0x" to your string first, to indicate that it's in base 16.

Comment: @JesperJuhl -- I think that the hex value here is the **bits** of the floating-point value, represented in hex. `std::strtod` doesn't handle that.

Comment: @PeteBecker You may be right. It's not really clear IMO.

Comment: @PeteBecker yes you are right

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use reinterpret_cast instead of the union.
Also the value you presented is different on a site for conversion from hex to double: https://gregstoll.com/~gregstoll/floattohex/

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double hexstr2double(const std::string& hexstr)
{
    double d = 0.0;

    try{
        *reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long*>(&d) = std::stoull(hexstr, nullptr, 16);
    }
    catch(...){}

    return d;
}

int main()
{
    char buffer[] = "4035e60c49ba5e35";
    cout<<sizeof(double)<<" "<<sizeof(unsigned long long)<<endl;
    cout<<hexstr2double(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```